# Can't log into Centos

Tags: centos, boot, fstab

I have a CentOs 6.5 mail server which was compromised and used to send spam therefore forcing us to do some hardening.

I followed [enter link description here](http://www.tecmint.com/linux-server-hardening-security-tips/) hardening tutorial to the letter which got us blocking some unwanted access.

However, seems like step 12 blocked root access with old password so we needed to reset. We rebooted the box and tried to get into single mode but the process terminates when trying to reboot I guess because of step 24 in the link above is causing the error below

```
facing.ext2: Unable to resolve 'LABEL=/boot'
```

And then this further below:

```
Give root password for maintenance (or type Control-D to continue)
```

I'm stuck at this. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Single-user mode often requires the existing root password. If it does, you can bypass it by doing 'init=/bin/bash' on the kernel command line.

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, I am not able to change fstab (read-only) or root password authentication token failure.

Comment: When you use `init=/bin/bash`, usually the root filesystem is mounted read-only; you can use `mount -o remount,rw /` to make it read-write again, allowing you to say (e.g.) `passwd root` to set the root password as you like.